# jquery parent child selecter returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why jquery parent child selector is not working here.

Here article element has it's children element section, and section contains html `select` tag.

So, with parent child logic, it has to work, isn't it ? It is returning undefined.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="slct_sec"]', function(){

    //This one is working
    var cls=$('section > select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
    
    //Not working
    var cls_1=$(this).parent('section').siblings('section > select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
 
   //Not working
    var cls_2=$(this).parent('article').children('section > select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
    alert(cls_1);
    alert(cls_2);
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <section>
        <select name='slct_cls'>
          <option value='1'>One</option>
          <option value='2'>Two</option>
        </select>
      </section>
      <br/>
      <section>
        <select name='slct_sec'>
          <option value='1'>A</option>
          <option value='2'>B</option>
        </select>
      </section>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to use parent child logic when you have the name of select `slct_sec` and `slct_cls` and not using `$('[name="slct_cls"])`. If there are other select boxes in the page with this same name, then I would suggest you to use unique names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't know the `section` corresponding to the element you want to target, the one with `select[name="slct_cls"]`, so you can't use `siblings` - with a sibling, you'd want to select the one with the `slct_cls`, but you don't know which sibling has that beforehand. Better to go one level higher, to the `article`, and use `.find` to find a descendant element with that selector:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="slct_sec"]', function() {
  var cls_1 = $(this).closest('article').find('select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
  console.log(cls_1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <section>
      <select name='slct_cls'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <br/>
    <section>
      <select name='slct_sec'>
        <option value='1'>A</option>
        <option value='2'>B</option>
      </select>
    </section>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).closest('article')` to get parent tagged `<article>` instead of `.parent('article')`.

```
var cls_1=$(this).closest('article').find('select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
```

or

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code. The problem was on the `sibling()` usage. The `select` is not the sibling of the `section`. Also you should use `parents()` instead of `parent()` to get all parents on your query.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="slct_sec"]', function(){
debugger;
    //This one is working
    var cls=$('section > select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
    
    //Not working
    var cls_1=$(this).parent().siblings('section').find('[name="slct_cls"]').val();
 
   //Not working
    var cls_2=$(this).parents('article').children('section').find('[name="slct_cls"]').val();
    alert(cls_1);
    alert(cls_2);
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <section>
        <select name='slct_cls'>
          <option value='1'>One</option>
          <option value='2'>Two</option>
        </select>
      </section>
      <br/>
      <section>
        <select name='slct_sec'>
          <option value='1'>A</option>
          <option value='2'>B</option>
        </select>
      </section>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```